# Unit test arrange not effect

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, junit

I have already set `isGpsEnabled` to false, but when I debug the test, it still shows as true. I have no idea why this is happening...

```
    @Before
    fun setupViewModel() {
        preferences = FakePreferences()
        connectivityObserver = FakeConnectivityObserver()
        locationRepository = FakeLocationRepository()
        weatherRepository = FakeWeatherRepository()
        weatherUseCase = WeatherUseCases(
            getAllWeather = GetAllWeather(weatherRepository),
            convertUnit = ConvertUnit(),
        )
        locationUseCases = LocationUseCases(
            ValidateCurrentLocation(locationRepository, preferences),
        )

        weatherInfoViewModel = WeatherInfoViewModel(
            appPreferences = preferences,
            connectivityObserver = connectivityObserver,
            locationUseCases = locationUseCases,
            weatherUseCases = weatherUseCase,
            locationRepository = locationRepository,
        )
    }
```

```
    @Test
    fun firstTimeRunAppAndGrantLocationPermissionButLocationServiceDisabled_navigateToSearch() =
        runTest {
            // Arrange
            locationRepository.isGpsEnabled = false
            assertTrue(weatherInfoViewModel.isInitializing.value)
            weatherInfoViewModel.onFirstTimeLocationPermissionResult(true)
            runCurrent()
            assertEquals(
                WeatherDestinations.SEARCH_ROUTE,
                weatherInfoViewModel.appRoute,
            )
            assertFalse(weatherInfoViewModel.isInitializing.value)
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Just in case, debug both the setup and your current breakpoint and check against the FakeLocationRepository's hash, to make sure they are the same instance and not a different one.

Comment: Thanks @Logain. I did debug carefully this morning as you advice and figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a debugging problem; try to make the `isGpsEnabled = false` in the FakeRepository, and re-check your debug breakpoint, if it is still true, it means something else is changing this value, so check other possible places from where this value is accessed and change.

**Other Possible problems:**

- Check if the isGpsEnabled property is being overridden somewhere else in the code. You can try searching for any other instances where the property is being set or accessed.
- As said by Logain, Make sure that the `locationRepository` instance that you are using in your test is the same one that is being used by the `WeatherInfoViewModel`. Modifications to one copy may not appear in others when creating multiple copies of an object.

If none of these solutions work, share with us the source code so we can debug it on our end !

Comment: Actually it went to that break point in @Setup, and didn't go to it again after set `isGpsEnabled = false` as I wish. Sorry guys for my careless debugging.

Testing seems much challenging to me. But it indeed help me fix a lot of bugs I couldn't imagine when running app on my own.

Comment: Do I need to close the question or anything bro ?

Comment: Yeah never abandon testing, even if it is hard, because it will pay off later! Thanks bro, you can close it yeah!